# Doctrine querybuilder - select query with a join for many to many in doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I am trying to create a select query in order to make a searchable index. The problem is, whenever I select an attribute for the joined class, I only receive the first result of all possible results. I tried to implode the array, but no success so far.

Example

```
        $query = $em->getRepository(Person::class)->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->Select('p.id', 'p.name')
        ->join('p.books', 'i')
        ->addSelect('i.bookname')
        ->groupBy('p.id')
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This returns an array with for every person his/her `id`, `name` and one (the first) `bookname`. What I cannot figure out is how to get all `booknames`, seperated by a comma or such. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: What is the need of `groupBy` here ?

Comment: Without the `GroupBy` I store (semi) duplicate lines in my index which in return change the results when searching the index.